# SSO in Cloud foundry with Gitlab User data

Tags: oauth, gitlab, cloud-foundry

we have the following situation. A Open Source Cloud Foundry installation and an independent Gitlab installation. I would like to use the Gitlab Token to identify User in the CF UAA, means everybody registered at the Gitlab is able to use CF.

Is there a possibility to combine this two system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not supported by UAA.
We have plans to add supports for Generic OAuth 2.0 based external identity providers in the future.